# Kotlin Runtime errors ClassCastException: Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm trying to store data to my SQLite database but whenever I  run the code  an error occurs specifically on line 37: as the Logcat demonstrates :

```
     "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.a7minworkout.WorkoutApp
        at com.example.a7minworkout.FinishActivity.onCreate(FinishActivity.kt:37)"
```

and this is the code line :

```
    Val do = (application as WorkoutApp).db.history do()
    addDateToDatabase(dao)
```

whenever I comment on this line the project runs fine but I won't be able to store data in my database, but I'm sure the problem is in this line
class FinishActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var binding: ActivityFinishBinding? = null

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityFinishBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding?.root)
    setSupportActionBar(binding?.toolbarFinishActivity)
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
    binding?.toolbarFinishActivity?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }

    binding?.btnFinish?.setOnClickListener {
        finish()

    }
```

//error from this line as Logcat shows Line:31

```
    val dao = (application as WorkoutApp).db.historyDao()
    addDateToDatabase(dao)

}

// START

private fun addDateToDatabase(historyDao: HistoryDao) {

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance() // Calendars Current Instance
    val dateTime = calendar.time // Current Date and Time of the system.
    Log.e("Date : ", "" + dateTime) // Printed in the log.

    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()) // Date Formatter
    val date = sdf.format(dateTime) // dateTime is formatted in the given format.
    Log.e("Formatted Date : ", "" + date) // Formatted date is printed in the log.
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        historyDao.insert(HistoryEntity(date)) // Add date function is called.
        Log.e(
            "Date : ",
            "Added..."
        ) // Printed in log which is printed if the complete execution is done.
    }
}
```

*//the workout app code:*

```
 class WorkoutApp: Application() {
     val db by lazy {
         HistoryDatabase.getInstance(this)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is it a compilation error or a runtime error? What is the error message?

Comment: I belive it's runtime error but the error message :caused by java.lang.classcastexception:
Android. App. Application cannot be cast to com.example.a7minworkout. WorkoutApp

at com.example.a7minworkout. Finish Activity.on create(Finish. Activity.kt:31)